# Keyboard movement Vuetify v-list-item

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a Vuetify v-list-item that is iterated over to create me a list, I want to be able to use the up and down arrows to traverse it. How can I do this? It doesn't seem to be default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The default focusing between elements behavior works through `tab`. You can try something like this in order to use arrows keys:

```
<template>
  <v-card
    class="mx-auto"
    max-width="300"
    tile
  >
    <v-list dense>
      <v-subheader>REPORTS</v-subheader>
      <v-list-item-group
        v-model="selectedItem"
        color="primary"
      >
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(item, i) in items"
          :key="i"
        >
          <v-list-item-icon>
            <v-icon v-text="item.icon"></v-icon>
          </v-list-item-icon>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="item.text"></v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list-item-group>
    </v-list>
  </v-card>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      selectedItem: 1,
      items: [
        { text: 'Real-Time', icon: 'mdi-clock' },
        { text: 'Audience', icon: 'mdi-account' },
        { text: 'Conversions', icon: 'mdi-flag' },
      ],
    }),
    methods: {
        nextItem () {
            if (event.keyCode == 38 && this.selectedItem > 0) {
                this.selectedItem--
            } else if (event.keyCode== 40 && this.selectedItem < 3) {
                this.selectedItem++
            }
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        document.addEventListener("keyup", this.nextItem);
    },
  }
</script>
```